# Problems installing RCPLEX

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix, r

I get an error while I try to install RCPLEX on my Computer and I can't figure out what to do. There is no information what so ever on the internet regarding my problem.

```
R Marcel$ R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="PKG_CFLAGS='-m64 -fPIC' PKG_CPPFLAGS=-I/Users/Marcel/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include/ilcplex PKG_LIBS='-L/Users/Marcel/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic -lcplex -lm -m64 -lpthread -framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKit'" Rcplex
* installing to library ‘/Users/Marcel/Library/R/3.5/library’
* installing *source* package ‘Rcplex’ ...
** Paket ‘Rcplex’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
checking for gcc... clang
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... clang -E
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
no
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking ilcplex/cplex.h usability... no
checking ilcplex/cplex.h presence... no
checking for ilcplex/cplex.h... no
configure: error: CPLEX header cplex.h not found
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rcplex’
* removing ‘/Users/Marcel/Library/R/3.5/library/Rcplex’
```

I am using Mac OS Mojave and I followed every step from this instruction and everything worked out fine until step 2:
http://jrzubizarreta.com/INSTALL

R, IBM CPLEX, R studio, my computer... everything is 64 bit as required.

The path and the file "cplex.h" is there. I checked it. 
I sadly have no experience with makefiles or compilers.
I would be grateful if someone could please help me!